# Replace the dataframe if contain

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I am a beginner to python.

I got a data frame like the pic.

I want to replace the cells to 0 if it contains "<"

```
Col = list(Frame.columns)

for i in Col:
    Frame.loc[Frame[i].str.contains('<', case=False), i] = '0'
    print(Frame)
```

But it now work, anyone can help.

Comment: Can you paste your dataframe either as a dict with `Frame.to_dict()` or just the output of printing it? (Formatted as code, editing your question)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with me, but you also can try `applymap`

```py
out = df.applymap(lambda s: 0 if '<' in str(s) else x)
```

It seems your column contains nan value, so that you need use

```py
Frame.loc[Frame[col].str.contains('<', case=False, na=False), col] = '0'
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much!
however I don't know why the code I writ doesn't work :(
show : ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Comment: @Shawn Update the answer.